# unix shell script syntax issue?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have an environment variable

```
net_connect="@oradb"
```

So I am trying to store that value in another environment variable without the @ character

So doing this seems to work:

```
echo "test=" $net_connect | cut -d "@" -f2
test=oradb
```

Now if I do this I get:

```
SID=`$net_connect | cut -d "@" -f2`
echo "SID=" $SID
SID=
```

Why is my output blank?

Comment: Your first line associates the commands like this : PIPE `echo test= $net_connect` STDOUT  INTO `cut -d @ -f2` STDIN. I don't know how it's working in your shell. Mine returns `oradb`

Answer (score 4):

To remove the `@`, use *prefix removal*:

```
$ net_connect="@oradb"
$ sid="${net_connect#@}"
$ echo "$sid"
oradb
```

Notes:

1. In general, `${variable#prefix}` removes the glob `prefix` from `variable`.  For more information, open `man bash` and search on `Remove  matching  prefix pattern`
2. In shell, it is best practices to name your variables with mixed or lower case.  If you use upper case variable names, then eventually you will, by accident, overwrite one of the system's variables and the results will be unpleasant.
3. The following command does not do what you hope:

   ```
   SID=`$net_connect | cut -d "@" -f2`
   ```

   It runs the command `$net_connect` and sends its stdout to `cut`.  But, there is likely no such command and the shell will issue an error such as:

   ```
   bash: @oradb: command not found
   ```

   If you really wanted to use `cut`, then:

   ```
   sid=$(echo "$net_connect" | cut -d "@" -f2)  # This works but prefix removal is simpler
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're executing the variable, not echoing it:

`$net_connect | etc...`

boils down to

```
@oradb | etc...
```

which is a syntax error. You have no command/binary named `@oradb`.

Maybe you wanted

```
SID=`echo $net_connect | cut -d "@" -f2`
```

instead.